# How do I separate two validation forms on one view?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a log-in form and a create member form on ONE view on my site in CodeIgniter.

The problem is that when I submit the form with an error (press submit with empty fields for the password and email on the LOGIN form), it triggers the email and password fields in the create member form and vice versa.

I have given them different submit button names and still can't get them to separate.

I have tried renaming fields,however I am confused on which values to rename as I have to submit specific values to my database.

Here is create member form and controller:

```
<?php

            echo form_open('auth/create_member');

            echo form_label('',  'email', array('type'=>'text'));
            $data = array( 'name' => 'first_name', 'class' => 'input', 'placeholder' => 'First Name' );
            echo form_input($data, set_value('first_name'));
            echo "<span class='errors'>";
            echo form_error('first_name');
            echo "</span>";

            echo form_label('',  'last_name', array('type'=>'text'));
            $data = array( 'name' => 'last_name', 'class' => 'input', 'placeholder' => 'Last Name' );
            echo form_input($data, set_value('last_name'));
            echo "<span class='errors'>";
            echo form_error('last_name');
            echo "</span>";

            echo form_label('',  'email', array('type'=>'text'));
            $data = array( 'name' => 'email', 'class' => 'input', 'placeholder' => 'Email' );
            echo form_input($data, set_value('email'));
            echo "<span class='errors'>";
            echo form_error('email');
            echo "</span>";

            echo form_label('',  'password', array('type'=>'password'));
            $data = array( 'name' => 'password', 'class' => 'password', 'size' => 30, 'placeholder' => 'Password'  );
            echo form_password($data, set_value('sha1(password)'));
            echo "<span class='errors'>";
            echo form_error('password');
            echo "</span";

            echo form_label('',  'password2', array('type'=>'password'));
            $data = array( 'name' => 'password2', 'class' => 'input', 'size' => 30, 'placeholder' => 'Confirm Password'  );
            echo form_password($data, set_value('sha1(password2)'));
            echo "<span class='errors'>";
            echo form_error('password2');
            echo "</span>";

            echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
            echo form_close();
            ?>

function create_member() 
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['main_content'] = 'home/home_page';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/home_page_template', $data);
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            if($query = $this->user_model->create_member())
            {
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $this->varification_email();
                $data['main_content'] = 'account/welcome';
                $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);

            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('home/home_page');
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the login form and controller:

```
<?php

                echo form_open('auth/validate_credentials_login');

                echo "<span class='errors_login'>";
                echo form_error('email');
                echo "</span>";

                echo form_label('',  'email',  array('type'=>'text'));
                $data = array( 'name' => 'email', 'class' => 'input', 'placeholder' => 'Email');
                echo form_input($data, set_value('email'));


                echo "<span class='errors_login'>";
                echo form_error('password');
                echo "</span>";

                echo form_label('',  'password', array('type'=>'password'));
                $data = array( 'name' => 'password', 'class' => 'input', 'placeholder' => 'Password');
                echo form_password($data, set_value('sha1(password)'));

                echo form_submit('submit_login', 'Login');
                echo form_close();

                ?>      

function validate_credentials_login()
   {
        // WHEN THE VIEW IS LOADED THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED AND LOADS MODEL AS WELL AS DEFINES THE SALT VARIABLE AND LOADS THE ENCRYPTING HELPER LIBRARY

        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('user_model', 'um');
        $login = $this->input->post('submit_login');





   if($login) {
                $user = $this->um->validate_home_login(array('email' => $this->input->post('email')));
                if( $user ) {

                    // CHECK THE USER'S PASSWORD AGAINST THE ONE FROM THE LOGIN FORM
                    if($user->password == $this->encrypt->sha1( $user->salt . $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password')))) {
                        $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                            'email' => $this->input->post('email')
                        ));
                        redirect('account/dashboard');
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }
   }
```

Comment: If you don't care about using the form_validation class you could also use the PHP function array_key_exists() to check if a certain button is in the POST or GET array.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you just all validation rules inside `if` block

Which means when submit was clicked..